# Chinese replicas of the E3D titan extruder

Tags: diy-3d-printer, e3d-titan

Has anyone used the Chinese replicas of the E3D titan extruders and multi-extrusion hotends? Are they reliable compared to the original ones?

Any other issues or advantages, please share.

Comment: I initially voted to close this as opinion based, but considering [Good subjective, bad subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) this question could be answered in a reasonably objective way by somebody reporting their actual experiences with these hotends. One problem is that there isn't one "canonical" supplier of replica hotends, so what you get might vary what somebody else gets but I'm not sure how to avoid that issue.

Comment: Hi this is not a valid question for this group. It is vague and more suited for a forum. I would recommend http://forums.reprap.org/ or a facebook group. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, Francis. As pointed out by others, your question is too broad and opinion based in its current form, and can hardly be answered objectively. I therefore have to put it *on hold* for now. You can vote for your question to be opened after eventual edits.

Comment: I think you will find an answer here: [Can cheap hotend parts sourced from China actually produce good prints?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4209/can-cheap-hotend-parts-sourced-from-china-actually-produce-good-prints)